# Is there a way to delete an entire Firebase Project with a Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Just wondering if there is a way to set up a Cloud Function to delete the entire Firebase Project.

Basically like a Self Destruct scenario.

Kind Regards.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/delete?

Comment: Frank Im sorry to ask is there a way to be able to do it with Postman or use it as an end point mostly due to the verification IAM I was able to tested from the try it in the link given using Auth 2.0, is there a way to set it up to use it from postman?

Comment: The entire flow is REST based, so should be possible in postman. If you are having trouble making it work there, it's more likely somebody can help you if you [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Frank this is the response on Postman: 

{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",

Comment: "metadata": {
                    "service": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
                    "method": "google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.Projects.DeleteProject"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Frank, Resource Manager has method called [**`Method: projects.delete`**](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/delete).

Here's a guide on using it on postman:

1. Open the Google Cloud Console.
2. At the top-left, click Menu menu > [APIs & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis?_ga=2.266302671.1332455811.1646022101-520961851.1645687647) > Credentials.
3. Click Create credentials > OAuth Client ID.
4. Select the appropriate application type for your project and enter any additional information required. For your use-case, choose **`Web Application`**. (If this is your first time creating a client ID, you can also configure your consent screen by clicking Consent Screen. The following procedure explains how to set up the Consent screen. You won't be prompted to configure the consent screen after you do it the first time.)
5. For `Authorized redirect URIs`, click `Add URI`. Go back to Postman, copy the `Callback URL` from Postman as highlighted green on the image below and paste it on the Add URI textbox.[image]
6. Click Create client ID.
7. A dialog box named `OAuth client created` will pop up after creating Client ID as shown in the image.
   [image]
8. Take note of Client ID and Client Secret. Click on the **`DOWNLOAD JSON`**. Securely save it somewhere safe.
9. Open the `JSON` file you've saved. `JSON` file should look like this:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback"
    ]
  }
}
```

10. Back to Postman Authorization Tab, Configure New Token.
    [image]
11. Fill out all information required:

    - `Token Name`: Any name you want.
    - `Grant Type`: Authorization Code.
    - `Auth URL`: "auth_uri" from JSON file.
    - `Access Token URL`: "token_uri" from JSON file.
    - `Client ID`: "client_id" from JSON file.
    - `Client Secret`: "client_secret" from JSON file.
    - `Scope`: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" (For Reference: [**Authorization Scopes**](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/delete#authorization-scopes))
    - `Client Authentication`: Send as Basic Auth header.
12. Click `Get New Access Token`.
13. Follow the prompt login on your screen. Your **`Access Token`** is now generated.
14. Click **`Use Token`**.
15. You should now be able to Send a **`DELETE`** request.

Comment: I think it will work, the problem is the Consent Screen, which is telling me that it will take a few weeks to be authorized so I'll wait for confirmation, unless I could do something else